# How to change column to header in excel?

Tags: excel, header, row

a1 | b1 | 0.1

a1 | b2 | 0.2

a2 | b1 | 0.3

a2 | b2 | 0.4

how to transform this table to

xx | a1 | a2

b1 | 0.1 | 0.3

b2 | 0.2 | 0.4

Answer (score 1):

Make use of Pivot tables. Enter Column A as `Column labels`, Column B as `Row Labels` and Column C as `Values`. If values are not sum by default, change it to `Sum`.

Output:

[image]

You can remove the headers deselecting the `Field Headers` in `Options` tab.

You can also hide the grand totals  by clicking on `Options` under the same tab. (Located at the left corner of the screen).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want Grand Total and other..., you can use Index:

- Create a New Sheet with your Header xx, a1, a2
- Copy column B b1, b2,...to the new sheet under xx
- select the Data b1, b2,... in the new sheet
- Remove Duplicates

Distinct and unique values will remain
Under a1 write the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$C$1:$C$4,MATCH(B$1&$A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4&Sheet1!$B$1:$B$4,0)),"")
```

Array Formula press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the same time instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>
and drag it in the same row and down in columns
Change A1:A4, B1:B4 and C1:C4 to correspond your last row of Data but keep $ for fixed references